# Prove $f$ is continuous on R

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Prove that if $f$ is defined on ***R*** and continuous at $x_0=0$ and if $f(x_1+x_2) = f(x_1)+f(x_2)$
∀ $x_1,x_2$ ∈ ***R*** , Then $f$ is continuous on ***R***

From $x_0$ being continuous we know $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)= f(x_0)=f(0)$

But I'm not sure how to continue and show f is continuous on all ***R***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f(0)= f(0) + f(0)$, it follows that $f(0)=0$. So if $x_n\to x$, we have
$$|f(x_n)-f(x)| = |f(x_n-x)|\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow0. $$